# How to re-run scala script with -deprecation?

Tags: scala

Running a certain Scala script gives this warning:

```
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
```

How do I do that?

Yes, I have RTFM, but what it says (separate the compiler arguments and the other arguments with a `-`) doesn't work.

Comment: The reason was of course that the name of the script always goes first, so you can't specify compiler arguments on the script's command line. You have to specify them inside the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the Scala interpreter (when used to execute scripts) supports shebang syntax ('#!').
Neither scalac nor the scala REPL supports it. See [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5179) for issue tracking.

See below for an answer that works with a shebang.

### What you may want to consider instead of using '#!'

In order to be able to use a file both in the REPL *and* the interpreter (*and* possibly as source code as well, e.g. if it's a valid class), you should give up on the shebang header altogether, and possibly add an launcher script (e.g. have an executable 'foo' that launches 'scala foo.scala').

Let's define 'foo.scala' as the following one-liner:

```
case class NoParens // <-- case classes w/o () are deprecated
```

This will work with both the interpreter:

```
$ scala foo.scala
```

...the compiler

```
$ scalac foo.scala
```

... and the REPL:

```
$ scala -i foo.scala

// or:

$ scala
scala> :load foo.scala
```

All of the above will give you the vague deprecation warning seen in your question.
For script execution via the 'scala' executable, as well as for compilation via 'scalac', all you have to do is add a '-deprecation' argument to the command line:

```
$ scala -deprecation foo.scala

// or:

$ scalac -deprecation foo.scala
```

Both will now give you detailed deprecation warnings (same goes for '-feature').

The REPL provides you with 2 options:
1) add the -deprecation argument as above (exercise left for the reader)
2) use ':warnings' at the REPL, like so:

```
$ scala -i foo.scala
Loading foo.scala...
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
defined class NoParens

Welcome to Scala etc...

scala> :warnings
<console>:7: warning: case classes without a parameter list have been deprecated;
use either case objects or case classes with `()' as parameter list.
case class NoParens // <-- case classes without () are deprecated
                   ^

scala>
```

Needless to say, the same goes for using ':load' from the REPL.

### Using '-deprecation' with '#!'

As promised, here's a recipe for using shebang syntax. I don't usually use it myself, so comments are welcome:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala $0 $@
!#

case class NoParens // <-- case classes w/o () are deprecated
```

This will provide you with a mysterious warning:

```
$ ./foo.scala
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
one warning found
```

To receive your warning in all its glory, just add a '-deprecation' right after 'exec scala', like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -deprecation $0 $@
!#

// etc...
```

This will yield the desired 'warning: case classes without a parameter list have been deprecated' etc...

Well, that about covers it. 360° of deprecation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Turn the script into an application:

1. Remove any `#! ... !#` bit at the top (this is used for executable scripts on Unix/Mac)
2. Wrap everything in `object Foo extends App { ... }`

Then compile it with

```
scalac -deprecation filename.scala
```

to see the detailed deprecation warning.

Answer (score -1):

The warning you are receiving is a compiler error. Scala has two compilers that are likely to be called from a script: scalac and fsc. Find where the script is calling one of these and edit the compiler call to include the flag -deprecation.

eg.

```
scalac -arg1 -arg2 big/long/path/*.scala other/path/*.scala
```

becomes

```
scalac -deprecation -arg1 -arg2 big/long/path/*.scala other/path/*.scala
```

Comment: The script isn't directly calling either of them. It's calling scala, the scala interpreter. That is how scala scripts are executed.